# Optimal solution for Word Count of a huge file using Redis

Tags: java, memory-management, redis, word-count, jedis

I want to do word count of a huge file using java. I can't use map reduce due to a single machine. Instead of using Hash Map I want to use Redis to store the frequency of word. In practical data is coming in a stream.

What I thought the I will push the  word count for each in redis sorted set. But I don't know it is optimal solution of not. Please provide the optimal solution to count the word of streaming data.

Java code for word count -

```
public class WordCount {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Map<String, Integer> wordMap = wordMap("filename");
        List<Entry<String, Integer>> list = sortByValue(wordMap);
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : list) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " => " + entry.getValue());

        }
    }

    public static Map<String, Integer> wordMap(String fileName) {
        Map<String, Integer> wordMap = new HashMap<>();
        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
                DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dis))) {
            // words are separated by whitespace
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s+");
            String line = null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                line = line.toLowerCase();
                String[] words = pattern.split(line);
                for (String word : words) {
                    if (wordMap.containsKey(word)) {
                        wordMap.put(word, (wordMap.get(word) + 1));
                    } else {
                        wordMap.put(word, 1);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ioex) {
            ioex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return wordMap;
    }

    public static List<Entry<String, Integer>> sortByValue(Map<String, Integer> wordMap) {
        Set<Entry<String, Integer>> entries = wordMap.entrySet();
        List<Entry<String, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>(entries);
        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Integer> o1, Map.Entry<String, Integer> o2)

            {
                return (o2.getValue()).compareTo(o1.getValue());
            }
        });
        return list;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a good [example](https://github.com/redisson/redisson/wiki/9.-distributed-services#952-distributed-mapreduce-service-map-example) of how to execute Map Reduce over Redis data on Java using [Redisson](https://redisson.org).